# How to calculate angle of inclination attained by a weigh balance on unequal loading?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, moment

Actually I need to rotate a beam (pivoted at center) with constant angular velocity using the principle of mass imbalance.

Could anyone suggest what would be the rate of decrease of mass in one pan (while the weight in other pan is kept constant) to achieve uniform velocity rotation?
How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint: Since it isn't accelerating, moment about the pivot (or for that matter, any point) will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the balance rotating with uniform angular velocity, you must ensure that gravity (being the only force) must not do any work on any part of the system and the system as a whole. The way to do this is to keep the center of mass of the system always at the pivot throughout the motion so that torque due the balance's own weight is zero always. That is, if you are loading mass onto the pans, they better be equally loaded throughout the motion. Otherwise, if the center of mass is off-center at any instant (one pan is more loaded than the other),torque would act and the angular velocity would change at **that** instant itself. Thus not maintaining 'constant' angular velocity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a “beam” (like a 2x4 with a friction-less axle through is center of  gravity), and you want to produce a constant angular velocity, then bounce a small rubber ball off of one end of the beam. The angular impulse will produce an angular velocity which will not change in the absence of other torques.